# object is not being saved even after fstream.clear() in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am using C++ to write a music memorize game for my school project, here the Player **objects are not being saved** in the PLAYER_DATA.DAT file even i tried **clear()** function

here is the peace of code (as the whole code is 600+ lines)

```
    Player p_dat,plyr;
    plyr.getData();
    fstream P_file("PLAYER_DATA.DAT",ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary);
    while(P_file.read((char*)&p_dat, sizeof(p_dat)))
    {
        if(nameEqual(plyr,p_dat))
        {
            P_file.clear();
            gotoxy(1,10);
            delline();
            textcolor(RED);
            cout<<"\t\t      EXIXTING PLAYER PROFILE FOUND!\n";
            int ch = playPanel("It's me", "Change Name");
            if(ch == 0)
            {
                P_file.seekp(P_file.tellg() - sizeof(Player));
                GameStarted = 1;
                if(c == 1)
                    Campaign(p_dat,P_file);
                else
                    Endless(p_dat,P_file);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                startGame(c);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    P_file.clear();
    P_file.seekp(0,ios::end);
    P_file.write((char*)&plyr,sizeof(plyr));
```

Just to make it short, The last line of the code is not doing anything the file already exists and of size 0kb
however,

```
fstream P_file("PLAYER_DATA.DAT",ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary)
P_file.write((char*)&plyr,sizeof(plyr));
```

is saving the file. Please help me.

## EDIT 1.1

finally found this line is problematic

```
P_file.seekp(0,ios::end);
```

Its working for code, i.e correctly saving objects

```
 P_file.clear();
 P_file.write((char*)&plyr,sizeof(plyr));
 P_file.seekp(0,ios::end);
```

while removing

```
 P_file.seekp(0,ios::end);
```

making the code look like,

```
P_file.clear();
 P_file.write((char*)&plyr,sizeof(plyr));
```

after the while loop, is not saving the file

again does not save the object
this line is making problem, are there any alternatives or solutions?

Comment: It would have been useful if you had error checking. `if (!P_file) { cerr << strerror(errno) << endl; }`

Comment: OT: if Player isn't a trivial type, you can't `write` it.

Comment: I can save it in other ways but however that seekp(0,ios::end); is required after writing data and I don't know why

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should provide some [MCVE] but you did not. Stack Overflow is not a *debug-my-code* service

Comment: Your full code is *not* an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) then **use the debugger** ([e.g. `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)).

Read carefully [documentation of C++ IO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) functions.

Check that your file has been opened correctly; after:

```
fstream P_file("PLAYER_DATA.DAT",ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary);
```

add

```
if (!P_file) { std::cerr << "failed to open PLAYER_DATA.DAT" << std::endl; };
```

On some systems (e.g. Linux), you might also display `strerror(errno)`.

After  some intermediate call to [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), consider using [`flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush).

Be sure that your program is started in the correct [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

On Linux, you might also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the system calls done by your program.

At last, did you consider using some simple [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), e.g. with [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/), or some indexed file, e.g. with [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/gdbm.html) ?

Comment: Thanks, by the way I am in windows. and with conio.h and using digital Mars compiler

Comment: But I still hope for you that you have some debugger available. AFAIK, `sqlite` exists on Windows. If you don't have a debugger, consider getting a compiler and a debugger capable of working together. BTW, Linux is an excellent system for developers and students, you should consider installing some Linux distribution (they all have compilers and debuggers)

Comment: that flush()... thanks for saving my project for class 12 board exams.